# Why does asynchronous function cause PropTypes to be null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple react app with Firebase with this structure

```
Project
 |    
 +-- src
 |  |  
 |  +-- component
             |
             +---SampleAppFolder
                      |
                      + index.js
                      + MySampleApp.js
 ...
```

in the `index.js` I have a create a **React component** `SampleAppPage` and I  try to pass the prop from the `SampleAppPage` to the `MySampleApp`, like this,

```
SampleAppPage extends React.Componet {

  render() {
    return (
    <MySampleApp varA={item.itemVarA} varB={item.itemData.itemVarB} varC={item.itemData.itemVarC || 0}/>
   )
  }
}
```

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class MySampleApp extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        varA: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
        varB: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        varC: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = INITIAL_STATE;
        this.varA = db.getByReference(A_NODE);
        this.varB = db.getByReference(B_NODE);
        this.varC = db.getByReference(C_NODE);
    };
```

In the debug mode, props were passed fine but in the render function for `MySampleApp`,

```
<Button icon='like' floated='right' onClick={this.foo} loading={loading}/>
```

I made a async call for this.foo function variable like this

```
foo = async () => {
      this.setState({ loading: true });

      try {
         console.log(this.props.varA); 
         console.log(this.props.varB);
         await db.pushToReference(); //asynchronous call to push data to Firebase Realtime database reference node

         this.setState({
             loading: false
         });
      }
      catch
      {


      }

}
```

Why varA and varB PropTypes were passed successfully in the `MySampleApp` constructor but when I called the async function, why varA prints the **value** but var B print **null**
?

Is it because the async operation in the function variable?

I'm quite new in the JavaScript space so please spare me some insights on the issue?

Comment: When you are passing `varB={item.itemData.itemVarB}` make sure it has a value may be `{item.itemData.itemVarB}` is already `null` when you passed it as props.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` to foo. Since it's an anonymous function.

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
 }
```

Comment: This works for me, can you also explain why `this.props.varA` works but `this.props.varB` was **null**?

Comment: Not sure but you should just be able to pass the full item as a prop to the component. Rather than 3 seperate props.